# Facing '403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table' while loading BQ table

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

#### Issue Summary

Facing an issue while loading bigquery table

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too
> many table update operations for this table

This task is executing in Airflow.

Note: Actually the DAG is processing more than 20 tables parallel and the {table}_count task is loading counts into same BQ table for individual tables. Verify task will fetch the data from the same loaded table at the end.

```
def create_load_count_task(db_name, gcs_name, table_name):
    task = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'my_{table_name}_count',
        op_kwargs={
            'dataset_name': DATASET,
            'file_name' : f'{table_name}_metadata.json',
            'file_prefix': f'{gcs_name}',
            'table_name': f'my_table_in_bq',
            'table_load_type': bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        },           
        python_callable=load_into_bq
    )
    
    return task


with open(f'mypath/tables.conf') as fp:
    for count, line in enumerate(fp):
        config = line.split(':')

        db_name = config[0].strip()
        gcs_name = config[1].strip()
        table_name = config[2].strip()
 
        load = < my code >
        check = < my code >
        verify = < my code >
        init = < my code >
        load_count = create_load_count_task(db_name,gcs_name,table_name)

        print_dag_info >> check >> init >> load_count >> load >> verify
```

#### My analysis

I thought the parallel loading and fetching causing the issue.

#### My try

I thought to implement delay_retry airflow operator as 10 secs will delay the task execution after the first failure.

Please help me in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GoolgeBigQuery - Exceeded rate limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844004/goolgebigquery-exceeded-rate-limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `retry_exponential_backoff` to `true` & `retries` `2` at DAG level is resolved my issue.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'my-owner-db',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are writing any bigquery update statement outside python function. Also bigquery has limitation of 1500 DMl operations per day per table.

Comment: No BQ updates from outside python function.