# How do I collect all outputs from a kubeflow parallel for loop?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, parallel.for

I'm running a time series model in kubeflow using python's SDK package - `kfp.v2`.  I need to run this model pipeline, then "walk" one month forward and run it again and so on for 24 months to get multiple snapshots in time.

That said, I don't know how to collect all of the final output into one place so I can concatenate and batch load it into a `Big Query` table.

I tried loading into the table direct from each loop, but that results in an `Error 403: Exceeded rate limits.  Exeeded the number of uploads to this table`.

Is there a way to collect all of the results so I can concatenate and load once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when you hit this quota, 5 ops / 10s. Which can be resolved by limiting your rate.

As given in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables):

> Your project can make up to 1,500 table modifications per table per
> day, whether the modification appends data, updates data, or truncates
> the table. This limit includes the combined total of all load jobs,
> copy jobs, and query jobs that append to or overwrite a destination
> table or that use a DML DELETE, INSERT, MERGE, TRUNCATE TABLE, or
> UPDATE statement to write data to a table.

Refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844004/goolgebigquery-exceeded-rate-limits) for more information.